# How to speed up making large dictionary

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

I have a large file (about 1GB) which I read in like this to create a dictionary of sorted lists. I need the lists to be sorted so I can search them later. These will be predecessor queries (as in which index has the biggest value smaller than x) so I can't use sets.

```
A = defaultdict(list)
B = defaultdict(list)
filename = sys.argv[1]

with open(filename) as fin:
    lines = list(fin)

for line in lines:
    vals=line.split()
    vals[2] = int(vals[2])
    bisect.insort_left(A[vals[1]],vals[2]]
    bisect.insort_left(B[vals[0]],vals[2]]
```

Unfortunately it is too slow.

Profiling I see that almost all the time is spent in `bisect.insort_left` call.

Is there any way to speed this up?

Would it be worth adding the elements unsorted and then sorting afterwards? If so, how can you sort all the lists in a dictionary of lists?

Comment: Why are you reading the file first, *then* looping over the lines? Why not just loop over the file instead?

Comment: I have to then loop over the file again using the dictionaries I made.

Comment: ^Ditto what Martijn said. You're turning your large file into a large list with `lines = list(fin)`. Files can be opened and iterated over over without turning the file into a list first. You should cut that line and go straight to: `for line in fin:`

Comment: [bisect.insort_left](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#bisect.insort_left) says "Keep in mind that the O(log n) search is dominated by the slow O(n) insertion step." It would be better to sort at the end.

Comment: @OmriBarel Oh! That's the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try 1) not reading the entire file in at once, and 2) sorting after the read is complete. Like this:

```
A = defaultdict(list)
B = defaultdict(list)
filename = sys.argv[1]

with open(filename) as fin:
    for line in fin:
      vals = line.split()
      vals[2] = int(vals[2])
      A[vals[1]].append(vals[2])
      B[vals[0]].append(vals[2])

for v in A.itervalues():
    v.sort();
for v in B.itervalues():
    v.sort()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating without making a list first

```
with open(filename) as f:
  for line in f:
    vals=line.split()
    vals[2] = int(vals[2])
    bisect.insort_left(A[vals[1]],vals[2]]
    bisect.insort_left(B[vals[0]],vals[2]]
```

another idea is to sort after all insertions are done

Comment: I think I need to sort after the insertions are done because of the point Omri Barel made.